# Twitter API - simpler authentication if I just need to update my own status?

Tags: php, twitter, tweets

I am asking this question just as a confirmation before wasting many hours developing. I guess the answer to my own question is YES.

I have a PHP webapp that needs to tweet [programmatically!] once a day using my OWN personal Twitter account - just that - I am not going to allow other users to use my app.

Do I still need to go through the creation of an app on the Twitter dev center and authentication with OAuth?

I was hoping there was a simpler way for such a simple use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** you need to create application. But nowadays you don't have to implement twitter login on your page if you need only your own oAuth credentials - you can find pair of key/secret on dev.twitter.com .